# PHP Query select one record

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I just started with PHP and I don't understand why this line won't work

```
$zoek = '2341 KG';
foreach ($pdo->query ("select * from blad1 where Postkode = $zoek" ) as $klant)
```

but this one does work perfect

```
foreach ($pdo->query ("select * from blad1 where Postkode = '2341 KG' " ) as $klant)
```

Comment: Why don't you bind the parameter properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should prepare that query.

```
$stmt = $pdo ->prepare("select * from blad1 where Postkode = ?" );
$stmt->execute(array($zoek)); 
$klant = $stmt->fetch();//no loop it's a single record!
```

Comment: it's not an issue, just cleaner. +1 for binding :)

Comment: Thank you, this one works fine for me. I will lookup, how and why I should prepare this query

Comment: Can you remove the part about quoting entirely? The placeholder method is the only reasonable way to do this here. That first example is a [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @tadman I removed that part, it was just an attempt to answer as to why it didnt work. is that why im getting downvoted?

Comment: I flipped it after you fixed it. Thanks! Explanations are fine, but code that works and exposes people to serious risk is not a great way to start an answer.

Comment: So everytime I want to read one single record, I need to put in 3 lines of code??

Comment: I hardly believe it need for a simple database read action this mutch of complex code. Isn't there a simple thing in PHP like '$record = get (key)'. The suggested answer works, but too much code for a simple action for me

Comment: @Richard are you available for chat ? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56161/meda